# Custom keyboard with changed numbers every time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working over my some random dribble ui/ux designs and this design came and I am struggling with creating logic of it about how it will work.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEGNj.png) Its a secured keyboard for digits password and for otp the numbers are scrambled every time when user uses the app I'm stuck with this part for ages now please if anyone can help it is a unique problem it will definitely help others as well. Check my code as reference below note its not complete code its part of it only the otp keyboard.

```
class _OtpState extends State<Otp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final int time = 180;
  AnimationController _controller;

  Size _screenSize;
  int _currentDigit;
  int _firstDigit;
  int _secondDigit;
  int _thirdDigit;
  int _fourthDigit;
  int _fifthDigit;
  Timer timer;
  int totalTimeInSeconds;
  bool _hideResendButton;



get _getInputField {
    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        _otpTextField(_firstDigit),
        _otpTextField(_secondDigit),
        _otpTextField(_thirdDigit),
        _otpTextField(_fourthDigit),
        _otpTextField(_fifthDigit),
      ],
       );
  }

 get _getOtpKeyboard {
    return new Container(
        height: _screenSize.width - 20,
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "1",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(1);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "2",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(2);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "3",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(3);
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "4",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(4);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "5",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(5);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "6",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(6);
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "7",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(7);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "8",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(8);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "9",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(9);
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _otpKeyboardActionButton(
                      label: new Image.asset(
                        "assets/cancel.png",
                        scale: 1.3,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (_fifthDigit != null) {
                            _fifthDigit = null;
                          } else if (_fourthDigit != null) {
                            _fourthDigit = null;
                          } else if (_thirdDigit != null) {
                            _thirdDigit = null;
                          } else if (_secondDigit != null) {
                            _secondDigit = null;
                          } else if (_firstDigit != null) {
                            _firstDigit = null;
                          }
                        });
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "0",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(0);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardActionButton(
                      label: new Icon(
                        Icons.check_rounded,
                        color: Color(MainAppColor),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => CreatePin(),
                            ));
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),

Widget _otpKeyboardInputButton({String label, VoidCallback onPressed}) {
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: new InkWell(
        onTap: onPressed,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
        child: new Container(
          height: 80.0,
          width: 80.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey[300]),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(
              label,
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _otpKeyboardActionButton({Widget label, VoidCallback onPressed}) {
    return new InkWell(
      onTap: onPressed,
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
      child: new Container(
        height: 80.0,
        width: 80.0,
        decoration:
            new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey[300]),
        child: new Center(
          child: label,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _setCurrentDigit(int i) {
    setState(() {
      _currentDigit = i;
      if (_firstDigit == null) {
        _firstDigit = _currentDigit;
      } else if (_secondDigit == null) {
        _secondDigit = _currentDigit;
      } else if (_thirdDigit == null) {
        _thirdDigit = _currentDigit;
      } else if (_fourthDigit == null) {
        _fourthDigit = _currentDigit;
      } else if (_fifthDigit == null) _fifthDigit = _currentDigit;
      // ignore: unused_local_variable
      var otp = _firstDigit.toString() +
          _secondDigit.toString() +
          _thirdDigit.toString() +
          _fourthDigit.toString() +
          _fifthDigit.toString();
    });
  }

  Future<Null> _startCountdown() async {
    setState(() {
      _hideResendButton = true;
      totalTimeInSeconds = time;
    });
    _controller.reverse(
        from: _controller.value == 0.0 ? 1.0 : _controller.value);
  }

  void clearOtp() {
    _fifthDigit = null;
    _fourthDigit = null;
    _thirdDigit = null;
    _secondDigit = null;
    _firstDigit = null;
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the best solution so far for you its still not the best though but it will help a lot. Use pinpad package it will fulfill the random keys task for you easily and you may try your best to customize the keyboard as much as you can.

[URL to PinPad Package](https://pub.dev/packages/pinpad)

Good Luck